# Installing GDB with All Targets on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: macos, gdb, homebrew

I'm unable to install gdb with all targets enabled on Mac OSX Mojave (10.14) using Homebrew (2.0.0).

I've tried:
`brew install gdb --enable-targets=all`
and
`brew install gdb --with-all-targets`
and receive `Error: invalid option: --enable-targets=all` and `Error: invalid option: --with-all-targets`

`brew info gdb` returns:

```
gdb: stable 8.2.1 (bottled), HEAD
GNU debugger
https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gdb.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
gdb requires special privileges to access Mach ports.
You will need to codesign the binary. For instructions, see:

  https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

On 10.12 (Sierra) or later with SIP, you need to run this:

  echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
==> Analytics
install: 13,521 (30 days), 42,502 (90 days), 153,991 (365 days)
install_on_request: 12,161 (30 days), 37,200 (90 days), 132,057 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Please note that none of the options are listed in the `info` that show in the gdb.rb link. What am I missing here?

Other options, like `--disable-debug` do not work either. If I remove all options, the install works fine.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gdb.rb

Taking a look at the formula, it seems those options are already enabled?

Comment: @RichardBarber thanks for pointing this out. I thought that since no options were listed with `info` that they were not being used. I mistakenly went down this path because of the `warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description` msg I was getting when trying to remotely debug an ARM chip. Which was actually caused because I had not used `set architecture arm`. Anyway, after you posted, I uninstalled my version and did a regular `brew install gdb` and it works with other targets. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just figured it out. I created a modified version of the formula .rb file in my /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gdbCustom.rb and added the missing build options. I based it on this formula: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/9ec9fb27a33698fc7636afce5c1c16787e9ce3f3/Formula/gdb.rb

Yes, I'm a newbie to Homebrew, but have a better understanding of how formulas work now. In case it helps others, see below final .rb. After adding the file to the above `homebrew-core/Formula` directory, run `brew install gdbCustom --with-all-targets`. The `make` takes several minutes, so be patient.

```
class Gdbcustom < Formula
    desc "GNU debugger"
    homepage "https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/"
    head "https://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git"

    stable do
      url "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.2.1.tar.xz"
      mirror "https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gdb/gdb-8.2.1.tar.xz"
      sha256 "0a6a432907a03c5c8eaad3c3cffd50c00a40c3a5e3c4039440624bae703f2202"

      # Fix build with all targets. Remove for 8.3
      # https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=0c0a40e0abb9f1a584330a1911ad06b3686e5361
      patch do
        url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/d457e55/gdb/all-targets.diff"
        sha256 "1cb8a1b8c4b4833212e16ba8cfbe620843aba0cba0f5111c2728c3314e10d8fd"
      end

      # Fix debugging of executables of Xcode 10 and later
      # created for 10.14 and newer versions of macOS. Remove for 8.3
      # https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;h=fc7b364aba41819a5d74ae0ac69f050af282d057
      patch do
        url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/d457e55/gdb/mojave.diff"
        sha256 "6264c71b57a0d5d4aed11430d352b03639370b7d36a5b520e189a6a1f105e383"
      end
    end

    bottle do
        sha256 "01b06c2983503c78bc346b5f5e2c2bdccbc41d6f5ca759542eef712bf123ca30" => :mojave
        sha256 "9824d06b8d0d44e725a1d29f6631828b3b43abb1952c883e9fad559b6a816c04" => :high_sierra
        sha256 "cf7371e9f6257d1a7dee80239d05917e424e5bb3e7577bd93f0e139fe5174198" => :sierra
    end

    # Owen: deprecated_option "with-brewed-python" => "with-python"
    # Owen: deprecated_option "with-guile" => "with-guile@2.0"

    option "with-python", "Use the Homebrew version of Python; by default system Python is used"
    option "with-version-suffix", "Add a version suffix to program"
    option "with-all-targets", "Build with support for all targets"

    depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
    # Owen: depends_on "python" => :optional
    # Owen: depends_on "guile@2.0" => :optional

    fails_with :clang do
        build 800
        cause <<~EOS
          probe.c:63:28: error: default initialization of an object of const type
          'const any_static_probe_ops' without a user-provided default constructor
        EOS
    end

    fails_with :clang do
      build 600
      cause <<~EOS
        clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
        Test done on: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
      EOS
    end

    def install
      args = %W[
        --prefix=#{prefix}
        --disable-debug
        --disable-dependency-tracking
        --enable-targets=all
        --with-python=/usr
        --disable-binutils
    ]

        # Owen: args << "--with-guile" if build.with? "guile@2.0"
        # Owen: args << "--enable-targets=all" if build.with? "all-targets"

      if build.with? "python"
        args << "--with-python=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"
      else
        args << "--with-python=/usr"
      end

      if build.with? "version-suffix"
        args << "--program-suffix=-#{version.to_s.slice(/^\d/)}"
      end

      system "./configure", *args
      system "make"

      # Don't install bfd or opcodes, as they are provided by binutils
      # Owen: inreplace ["bfd/Makefile", "opcodes/Makefile"], /^install:/, "dontinstall:"

      # Owen: system "make", "install"
      system "make", "install-gdb"
    end

    def caveats; <<~EOS
      gdb requires special privileges to access Mach ports.
      You will need to codesign the binary. For instructions, see:

        https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

      On 10.12 (Sierra) or later with SIP, you need to run this:

        echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
      EOS
    end

    test do
      system bin/"gdb", bin/"gdb", "-configuration"
    end
  end
```

Comment: This no longer works for me. `Error: invalid option: --with-all-targets`

Comment: @mhenry You can simply try - `brew install gdbCustom with-all-targets `. It worked for me.

Comment: Do we have sha for monterey as it complains `Invalid bottle tag symbol`.